# Split input with two termination numbers into two arrays c#

Tags: c#

Lets assume we have an input from keyboard.

I dont know the length of the input, but I know that the first part is an array of integers, where consecutive groups of three numbers describe assets: `type,value,amount`.

then termination number is `-1` then I have another array of integers and then again termination number `-1`

For example:

```
1 500 5 2 25 100 3 10 50 -1 3 9 -1
```

So I want to have 2 containers to work with first is `{(1,500,5),(2,25,100),(3,10,50)}` and second is `{3,9}`.

How I can make this happen?

Comment: _"So I want to have 2 arrays"_ What you show after this sentence are _not_ two arrays. What _exactly_ is the type of the expected result?

Comment: I need to have 2 arrays or maybe List of <int,int,int> and array[int]

Comment: Have a look at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3L71bY

Comment: Are there any suggestions for the input to be from the keyboard and in the form of numbers and not string?

Comment: @StarTeker - don’t understand your question (pls use @(username) to notify users of a comment)

Comment: @RandRandom I tried your solution it works perfectly, if input is string. I need input to be something like array... like " int[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray(); "

Comment: @StarTeker - will have a look at it after watching WWDC

Comment: @StarTeker - how about this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ceBdHL - don't know about a in-built split operation for a int array, so I wrote own as a static extensio at the bottom, I also added a cheating method that simple joins the int array with a space to get the string (I am off for the day, further questions have to wait till tomorrow)

Comment: @StarTeker your question starts "Lets assume we have an input from keyboard" - input from the keyboard is always text, never anything else. Your comments say you have an array of integers not text. Can you edit your question to clarify what exactly you have? Why is the keyboard relevant?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a List of structs containing the asset data triples from the first part of the string, and an array of ints from the second part:

```cs
public struct assetData {
    public int type;
    public int value;
    public int amount;
};

void Main()
{
    string keyboard = "1 500 5 2 25 100 3 10 50 -1 3 9 -1";
    string[] parts = keyboard.Split("-1", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    int[] assetInput = parts[0].Trim().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
    int[] numbers    = parts[1].Trim().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

    // take 3 numbers at a time into assetData structs. Store them.
    var assetInfo = new List<assetData>();
    for (int i = 0; i < assetInput.Length; i += 3)
    {
        assetData item;
        item.type = assetInput[i];
        item.value = assetInput[i+1];
        item.amount = assetInput[i+2];
        assetInfo.Add(item);
    }
}
```

variant for array input:

```cs
public struct assetData {
    public int type;
    public int value;
    public int amount;
};

void Main()
{
    string keyboard = "1 500 5 2 25 100 3 10 50 -1 3 9 -1";
    int[] input = keyboard.Trim().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
    
    // 3 numbers at a time into assetData structs. Store them.
    var assetInfo = new List<assetData>();
    int i;
    for (i=0; input[i] != -1; i += 3)
    {
        assetData item;
        item.type = input[i];
        item.value = input[i+1];
        item.amount = input[i+2];
        assetInfo.Add(item);
    }
    
    i++; // skip the -1
    
    var numbers = new List<int>();
    while (i < input.Length - 1) {
        numbers.Add(input[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI - in the comments OP mentioned the input is an array of int and not a string